# I am trying to access the password box on a website using selenium. I have tried find_element_by_xpath but with no luck

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Trying to access password input boxes on website page using selenium

I have tried using `find_element_by_xpath`, by_id, etc

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import pandas as pd

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_DIR, options = option) 
driver.get("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
system = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='_id:logon:CMS']")
system.send_keys('xxxxxx')
```

and error it throws is

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element:
>   Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='_id:logon:CMS']"}
>   (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: The error message is : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@id='_id:logon:CMS']"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)     . I have tried this code before on other websites but cant get to work for this particular one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the form is inside ifame and you need first switch driver to that iframe. (I noticed as well that id of that input is not `_id:logon:CMS` but `_id0:logon:CMS`

```py
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import pandas as pd

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_DIR, options = option) 
driver.get("https://analytics.aspire.qa/BOE/BI")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.switch_to_frame('servletBridgeIframe')
system = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='_id0:logon:CMS']")
system.send_keys('xxxxxx')
```

Plus you don't need to use `driver.find_element_by_xpath` here. More convenient for this case is to use `driver.find_element_by_id`

Answer (score 0):

The button you're looking for belongs to the [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) therefore you will need to [wait for presence of the iframe and switch to it](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it)

Once done you should be able to locate the input you're looking for

Example code:

```
driver.get("https://analytics.aspire.qa/BOE/BI")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "servletBridgeIframe")))
system = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "_id0:logon:CMS")))
system.clear()
system.send_keys("foo")
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)